# sudoers to execute commands as another user

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I'd like to allow one of my users to execute commands as another user on my Ubuntu Lucid server.

I'm struggling with finding the syntax for the sudoers file to do this.  Say I'm connecting to the box with a user called 'ludo', and I want ludo to be able to execute commands as the 'django' user.  eg:

sudo -u django

I'd like to be able to execute /any/ commands as the django user, and without prompting for a passsword.  All the examples I find are for a restricted subset.  I did attempt something but got a syntax error upon exiting visudo so I bottled it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can put the user to run as in parentheses before the command list:

```
ludo ALL = (django) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 3):

For a finer grained control you could consider defining the specific command that `ludo` will be running as `django`.

```
ludo  ALL=(django) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [sudoers(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) adding the line `ludo            ALL = /usr/bin/su django` in the sudoers file should do the trick.