# Linux: Allow user to execute specific command on behalf of any other user

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, su

I am trying to find a way to allow user john to execute a command (say echo) on behalf of another user peter without being prompted for password.

[I found a thread that I thought would be the answer to my question:](https://serverfault.com/questions/197340/sudoers-to-execute-commands-as-another-user)

```
john ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/echo
```

Unfortunately, this is not quite do what I want. This command executes the `echo` command as `peter` but in the context of `john`. That means the home directory remains that of `john`.

As the user `john`, if I run: "`sudo -u peter echo ~`", the response is: `/home/john`. I want it to be `/home/peter`.

The behaviour I was expecting is provided by the su command. As root, if I do: `su peter -c "echo ~"` , I get `/home/peter`.

The question this is, how do I get the behavior of `su`, without being root and without being prompted for password?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `-i` flag to make sudo read the login scripts & such and set the environment variables as they should be.  Without making sudo load the environment, the home environment variable is not updated to reflect the running-as-user.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is this what you have in mind? "sudo  -i -u  peter echo ~". Adding -i now prompts john for password.

Comment: hmmm... it shouldn't ask for a password if sudo does not require it... let me do some digging.

Answer (score 0):

"sudo -u peter echo ~"  will interpret the value of ~ before executing the command sudo.  Try

```
sudo -s -H -u peter echo \$HOME
```

or

```
sudo -i -u peter echo \$HOME
```

Also, to view all environment variables set by sudo try:

```
sudo -i -u peter export
# actually, use /usr/bin/env instead of export
```

UPDATE

When using -i or -s you are implying that the SUDO_COMMAND to run is the shell environment of the specified user.  So allowing for only /bin/echo is not sufficient, one would have to allow for all of /bin/bash to be available.

It seems that -H is enough to set HOME environment variable, but you cannot echo it with $HOME because that is a feature of a shell.  Other programs may be able to read the value of HOME via getenv() or similar methods.

```
sudo -H -u peter  /usr/bin/env | grep SUDO_COMMAND
SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/env

sudo -i -u peter /usr/bin/env | grep SUDO_COMMAND
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/bash -c /usr/bin/env
```

Comment: As soon as you add another option, sudo prompts for password.

Comment: Because you are only allowing "/bin/echo" but -i wants the command to be /bin/bash (or whatever is set in /etc/passwd as the shell)

Comment: Sorry. I am not quite sure i understand what else i should allow.

Comment: You don't need to change anything.  Your original setup is correct.  Your assumptions about testing with ~ are incorrect.